# Formik values didnt update after change

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I cant get the values from disabled input after fetch data. I think cause i put 2 condition in my input value component like this. is there a way to run properly from this code. i use formik to handle my form

```
<Input
      disabled={true}
      value={ProfileData ? moment(ProfileData.BirthDate).format('DD MMMM YYYY') : '' && formik.values.formA.ValueDesc5}
      type="text"
      name="formA.ValueDesc5"
      onBlur={formik.handleBlur}
      onChange={formik.handleChange}
/>
```

ProfileData is a state that contain User Profile

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I use Next JS 13.0.4 + Chakra UI + Formik 2.2.9 and I face the same issues as yours.

I use SWR to fetch data from my server:

```
const fetcher = async (id: string): Promise<Course> => {
return (await findCourseById(id)) as Course;

... 
  const { data: dbCourse, error } = useSWR(
    urlToServer,
    () => fetcher(id),
    {
      refreshInterval: 1000,
    },
  );

};
```

The key to solve the problem is that we need to `re-initialize` the default values of the form. I use **useFormik** hook, and it looks like this:

```
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: dbCourse?.name as string,
      description: dbCourse?.description as string,
    },
    validationSchema: updateCourseSchema,
    enableReinitialize: true, // <=== check this line
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
      console.log(values);
    },
  });
```

Let me know if it helps!